# Specifying spaces between words

Tags: python, tabs

how could I use whitespaces in python that in the could I can specify how mach the space between the words

print "John and (5 spaces) Mark went to (3 spaces) London"

how could I specify 5 spaces as a code without typing it as `"     "`

Comment: where are the lines coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
space = " "
print "John and{}Mark went to{}London".format(space*5,space*3)
```

[Here you can find more information](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: is there anyway to use for example \s{5} ?

Comment: @user3771924 that's regex syntax, not Python

Answer (score 0):

```
is there anyway to use for example \s{5} ?
```

Am I understood corectly:

```
space = " "
print "John and %s Mark went to %s London" % (space*5,space*3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers of spaces in the template string instead of the arguments to `format`:

```
>>> "John and{0:5s}Mark went to{0:3s}London".format("")
'John and     Mark went to   London'
```